# React native - NetInfo always get the same data

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have here a code to check the internet status if it's connected or not, the problem is I always get the same data whether the device is connected or disconnected in wifi.

Here is my code:

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = NetInfo.addEventListener((state) => {
      console.log('net state', state);
    });
    return () => {
      unsubscribe();
    };
  }, []);
```

Comment: are you try console.log(state.isConnected)?

Comment: Yes, but it always display `isConnected: false` even i'm connecting/disconnecting from wifi

Comment: did u import from https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-native-community/netinfo ?